# change a session to an email session

Tags: php, database

this session is about the username, and i want to make a session for an email, i tryd soo much but everything i try, doesnt work. Can someone help me to make a new session for email

```
<?php

session_start();
header('Content-type: text/html;charset=UTF-8');
if(!isset ($_SESSION['username']) and isset($_COOKIE['username'], $_COOKIE['password']))
{
    $cnn = mysql_query('select password,id from users where username="'.mysql_real_escape_string($_COOKIE['username']).'"');
    $dn_cnn = mysql_fetch_array($cnn);
    if(sha1($dn_cnn['password'])==$_COOKIE['password'] and mysql_num_rows($cnn)>0)
    {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $_COOKIE['username'];
        $_SESSION['userid'] = $dn_cnn['id'];
    }
}
?>
<?php

echo htmlentities($_SESSION['username']); 

?>
```

Comment: Is there a part of the above code you do not understand? I think if you understand the code, you should be able to make the change quite easily.

Comment: i did not make  everything of the script by myself and yes i thought also that i could it do on an aesy way, but im not very good (just learning)

Comment: Let us know which parts of this script you don't understand and we can help you to understand it.

Comment: thanks,  i think i unnderstand the output, but not alle the specafic things

Comment: Sorry, if you can't tell us what you don't understand, I cannot help you to understand it.

Comment: can you tell me what isset means?

Comment: isset checks to see if a particular variable has been declared and has a non-null value. !isset (not isset) checks the opposite. It checks to see if it has not been set. In most cases I prefer to use empty and !empty instead of isset and !isset as empty will also be true for variables that have an empty string etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for helping!

I did just a few second ago and it works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

**

yes!

```
session_start();
header('Content-type: text/html;charset=UTF-8');
if(!isset($_SESSION['username']) and isset($_COOKIE['username'], $_COOKIE     ['email']))
 {
  $cnn = mysql_query('select email, from users where              username="'.mysql_real_escape_string($_COOKIE['username']).'"');  $dn_cnn = mysql_fetch_array($cnn);
if(sha1($dn_cnn['email'])==$_COOKIE['email'] and mysql_num_rows($cnn)>0)
{
    $_SESSION['username'] = $_COOKIE['username'];
    $_SESSION['userid'] = $dn_cnn['email'];
}
 }
 ?>
 <?php

 echo htmlentities($_SESSION['userid']); 

?>
```

now i get as id 1 :( i dont want that id :P **

Comment: sha1 is used for password encryption, not e-mail

Comment: Just remove the sha1 because the e-mail probably is not encrypted in your database:

Comment: where is the $cnn)>0) for?

Comment: That means that rows were returned from the mysql_fetch_array($cnn) statement. If no rows came back that means nothing was found in your database. If one or more rows were returned, then mysql_num_rows($cnn) will be 1 (or more).

Comment: oh sounds important, 

and sorry for asking this but do you have a session script for echoing something elkse then username and id?

Answer (score -1):

You can do this way,

```
session_start();
header('Content-type: text/html;charset=UTF-8');
if(!isset ($_SESSION['username']) and isset($_COOKIE['username'],$_COOKIE['password']))
{
   $cnn = mysql_query('SELECT password,id,email from users where username="'.mysql_real_escape_string($_COOKIE['username']).'"');
   $dn_cnn = mysql_fetch_array($cnn);
   if(sha1($dn_cnn['password'])==$_COOKIE['password'] and mysql_num_rows($cnn)>0)
   {
    //$_SESSION['username'] = $_COOKIE['username'];
    $_SESSION['userid'] = $dn_cnn['id'];
    $_SESSION['email'] =  $dn_cnn['email'];
    }
}
```

This should set the session as an email. But remember you have to select email field from the users table if there is any email field that exists.

Comment: do you have an email field in your users table?? if yes what is the name for that email field??

Comment: no i do not use any important field for this script

Comment: OK, but you need to select email from the database to set it as a session.

Comment: (name in database:) email   

(email i want to display with session:) test@gmail.com

Comment: OK you have email field in which table in the database.